# Java - get the same weekly date range for the previous year

Tags: java, date, date-range

I need to obtain certain data for current week and the same week of the previous year based on the current date.

For example, today is 23/11/2017 - Thursday.
I have the next date range for current week: 20/11/2017 (Monday) - 23/11/2017 (Thursday).

What is the best way to obtain a corresponding weekly date range for the previous year ( 21/11/2016 (Monday) - 24/11/2016 (Thursday) )?

Comment: Please define what you mean by same week, is it fiscal week?

Comment: Yes, the financial week.

Comment: I need to get the weekly date range for the previous year based on days of week relative to the current date

Comment: It sounds to me like you always want to go 52 weeks backward. This way the week last year will be one day later (two days later if crossing February 29 in a leap year), which is as close as you can get if you want the same days of week. Would this be OK? Of course, if you go back from Monday December 31, you will hit Monday January 1, that is, you’re not even in the previous year.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear" because you have not defined what you mean by weeks, as others commented. Tip: [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make a **specification document**, which the business side should affirm.

> Today is 23/11/2017 - Thursday. So the current week is: 20/11/2017
>   (Monday) - 26/11/2017 (Sunday).
>
> In the previous year we take today 23/11/2017 and subtract a year..
>   That is a Wednesday 23/11/2016.
>
> We obtain the week: 21/11/2016 (Monday) - 27/11/2016 (Sunday).
>
> A. Irregularity: 29th of February becomes the 28th in the previous
>   year.
>
> B. We are interested only in Monday - Thursday of the result,
>   but do all,    so we can work on Saturday as well.

Then consider weeks & week numbers. **Alternative**:

> Today is 23/11/2017 - Thursday. This is the week with week number 47,
>   with *week year* 2017. (01/01/2017 would be in week 52 of week year
>   2016). Yield week 47 of previous week year 2016.
>
> A. 53 possibly becomes 52 if there is no week 53.
>
> B. Start of January
>   can be of the previous week year.

As you see, one should not simply implement, but document such business logic.

---

By the way the new java date time API is great.

Answer (score 0):

The hard parts are defining what you want and which time zone you want it in. The latter is true because at time of writing it is November 23 in Smolensk, but in other places in the world it is already November 24, so you need to decide.

I understand your problem this way, please check if correct: Find the date range from the beginning of this week (Monday) till today. Then find a range last year also from Monday till the same day of week as today, as close as possible to the same dates. This means that you will always want to go 52 weeks back. Then you will get dates that are one day later (two days later if crossing February 29 in a leap year), this will always be as close as you can get.

With `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, the code is simple:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"));
    LocalDate firstDayOfWeek 
            = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    System.out.println("This year: " + firstDayOfWeek + " - " + today);

    LocalDate firstDayLastYear = firstDayOfWeek.minusWeeks(52);
    LocalDate correspondingDayLastYear = today.minusWeeks(52);
    System.out.println("Last year: " + firstDayLastYear + " - "
                        + correspondingDayLastYear);
```

Running just now this printed:

```
This year: 2017-11-20 - 2017-11-23
Last year: 2016-11-21 - 2016-11-24
```

Please substitute your desired time zone instead of Europe/Moscow if this is not the one you want.

If you want to print the day of week too, use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("d/M/uuuu (EEEE)", Locale.forLanguageTag("ru"));
    System.out.println("This year: " + firstDayOfWeek.format(dateFormatter) + " - "
            + today.format(dateFormatter));
```

This prints:

```
This year: 20/11/2017 (понедельник) - 23/11/2017 (четверг)
```

If you run the code on December 31, 2018, you will not reach back into 2017:

```
This year: 2018-12-31 - 2018-12-31
Last year: 2018-01-01 - 2018-01-01
```

Again, check if this is what you want.